# XPath - how to select text

Tags: xml, xpath

How do I get `The quick brown fox.` in the following document:

```
<a>
   <b>
      Hello
      <c/>
      World
   </b>
   The quick brown fox.
</a>
```

Comment: `/a/text()[2]` but this solution is not universal, works for this case only.

Comment: @khachik, I believe this is incorrect. There is only one child text node of `a`.

Comment: @Yodan I'm sorry to ruin your belief about it, but `a` has two child text nodes - one is the whitespace between `<a>` and `<b>` and the second is the text needed to be extracted.

Comment: @khachik: Well, at least according to the .NET implementation (of `XmlNode.SelectNodes`), there is only one node that matches `/a/text()`. I think it ignores whitespace when there is *nothing but whitespace*, but includes whitespace when other characters are present.

Comment: @Yodan DOM, SAX, XPath, XML have their own specifications which don't depend on .NET or another implementations.

Comment: @khachik and @Yodan: Whether white space only text nodes are preserve or striped from the tree depends on the XML tree provider of host language. Microsoft products strip them by default.

Comment: Naturally. I stand corrected (and I admin I have never read these specifications; my answers were based on .NET experience). One should apparently be careful when using the .NET implementation due to its quirks (somehow this starts to look like IE6).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As discussed in comments, when dealing with mixed content is important to know whether white space only text nodes are being preserved or stripped.

Universal solution:

```
/a/text()[normalize-space()][1]
```

Meaning: *first not white space only text node child of `a` root element*

Other posibility:

```
/a/text()[last()]
```

Meaning: *last text node child of `a` root element*

Comment: I'd make that predicate `[normalize-space(.) != '']` to make it more explicit.

Answer (score 1):

`text()` selects all child text nodes of the current node, so `/a/text()` is the way to go. Just remember that you may need to do some string manipulation on the results, because an XML like this one:

```
<a>
   <b>
      Hello
      <c/>
      World
   </b>
   The quick <!--comment--> brown fox.
</a>
```

will return two text nodes ("the quick" and "brown fox"). Also, the text values will contain whitespace (e.g. the newline after `</b>` and before "the").

Answer (score 0):

you can start with /a/text() This will get you just the node texts not the tags.