# xpath select node by a child text node

Tags: xpath

Having the following markup:

```
<p>
  <span>text</span>
  foo
</p>
<p>
  <span>text</span>
  bar
</p>
<p>
  <span>text</span>
  baz
</p>
```

how can I select the second node based on the `bar` text using xpath?

Note that I do not want to *select* the text as it is discussed here: [XPath - how to select text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4374239/xpath-how-to-select-text)

what I need, is to select the parent node based on the containing text node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried

`//p[text()[normalize-space(.)='bar']]`